# Compare the OutputStream of a Socket with a DataOutputStream

Tags: java, sockets

I have a bunch of `DataOutputStream`s in `Hashtable outputStreams;`. There is a `Socket` for each of them. I want to loop through them but I want to exclude one particular `Socket`. I've been trying with the following algorithm but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for(Enumeration e = outputStreams.elements(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {

    DataOutputStream dout = (DataOutputStream)e.nextElement();
    OutputStream sdout = null;
    try {
        sdout = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (dout != sdout) {
        try {
            dout.writeUTF(message);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that a `Hashtable` will insert a copy of the instance into its backing structure. Andypandy is right about your problem, but then I wondered if a table of `OuputStream`s (where you wouldn't wrap the socket output stream) would fix it and it didn't.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Hashtable<Integer, OutputStream> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, OutputStream>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            ht.put( i, new DataOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()) );

        Socket sock = new Socket("google.com", 80);
        ht.put( ht.size(), sock.getOutputStream() );

        for(OutputStream dos : ht.values())
            System.out.println(dos);

        System.out.println(sock.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.net.SocketOutputStream@112b853
java.io.DataOutputStream@36428
java.io.DataOutputStream@a4b78b
java.io.DataOutputStream@e3f6d
java.io.DataOutputStream@1660d22
java.io.DataOutputStream@e84763
java.net.SocketOutputStream@1a6c368
```

The socket's output stream that is inserted into the table has a different address than that of the original output stream. Since there's no `equals` override, there's no easy way to meaningfully compare streams without having knowledge of their corresponding sockets. You should re-think your design completely, perhaps using the socket descriptor as your key.

Comment: Hashtable/Hashmap uses the equals and hashCode methods on the *keys*, not on the values.  Your code does show that socket.getOutputStream() returns a new instance of OuputStream on every invocation.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful. I will use the `Socket`s for the key instead of the `DataOutputStream`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is presumably not working because `socket.getOutputStream()` is returning the "raw" output stream, and somewhere you'll have created a `DataOutputStream` for each of those raw output streams.  These will never be the same.

My best guess what you're trying to achieve, would be to iterate through the sockets, skipping the one you don't want to write to, and *then* finding the respective DataOutputStream and writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As blackcompe pointed out, neither DataOutputStream nor OutputStream override Object.equals. So this does not help. Anyway the getOutpuStream() method might create a new Object anyway each time its called.

You will probably have to create new Objects that hold the Outputstreams and the information about their socket. And iterate over them.

Comment: Neither `DataOutputStream` nor `OutputStream` override `Object.equals`. Shouldn't `Object.equals` and the equality operator equate to the same result?

Answer (score 0):

The output stream of a socket is never equal to any instance of DataOutputStream. You need to rethink what it is you are actually asking here.